# nginx - modify final URL?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a configuration:

```
server { listen 80;
server_name    emby.my_domain;
location /emby {
     rewrite /emby/(.*) /$1 break;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8096;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     #auth_basic "Restricted";
     #auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
}
}
```

I need to type URL http://emby.my_domain/emby

What do I need to do not to type /emby at the end ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why have you put `/emby` in the configuration at all? You could just remove it.

Comment: Ok I have now:

    location \
    ....

however the initial issue remain the resulting URL in browser looks like:

http://emby.my_domain/emby/

And I want to to be able to use like:

http://emby.my_domain/

Comment: Maybe I am not right ?!

Comment: Yes it looks it does work !

Thanks @MichaelHampton

Interesting, so for ignorant newbies `location /emby` actually added this to my URL.  Right thinking ? 

Do I always have to enter `/`  at the end ?